# Updating a MySql date to the last day of a given month

Tags: mysql

I have 2 date fields in a table, I want to update the second one to the last day of 2 months ahead of the first field.

For example:

When `Date1 = '2018-01-01'`, I want `date2 = '2018-03-31'`

When `Date1 = '2018-02-01'`, I want `date2 = '2018-04-30'`

Can this be done in one command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. There's [`LAST_DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function, and there's `INTERVAL` syntax which will allow you to add 2 months.

This should work:

```
UPDATE table_name SET date2 = LAST_DAY(date1 + INTERVAL 2 MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
select date1, last_day(date_add(date,interval 2 month)) as date2
from tablename
```